# How to redirect all request to specific page in JSP

Tags: .htaccess, jsp

I am developing an application in JSP and I know Apache Tomcat does not support .htaccess file.

I want to redirect all the request to index.jsp for URI routing

in .htaccess file I have

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

How to achieve this with Tomcat 7 for JSP URI rewriting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a Filter in your application

Create the Filter class. Something like this:

```
public class SessionFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        try {
            requestDispatcher.forward(req, res);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

Then in your deployment descriptor (web.xml) include the following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>MySessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.SessionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MySessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

This will redirect every REQUEST (`<url-pattern>*</url-pattern>`) to the page `req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");`

Hope this helps